# Question about spalling on foundation

Tags: foundation

The foundation on one corner of my 2 story home seems to be disintegrating. I was told sprinklers were spraying water on it for years. I’ve been getting different opinions about the severity of this. Does this seem like something that needs repair?it’s post tension slab. [image: picture of spalling]